# Magento 2 :- Custom Price Set issue on cart page

Tags: magento2, cart, price, controllers

I have set custom product price using a controller and it works fine but when I go to cart page I see grand total not set to the zero.Because the summary section loads using the ajax after some time automatically.

I used this link in my controller :- **[I want to set custom price programmatically to the product Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216100/i-want-to-set-custom-price-programmatically-to-the-product-magento-2)**
Please see the screenshot I have attached below. first the order total and subtotal set to zero but after some time it loads automatically and set the price as default price.

```
foreach ($products_array as $value) 
{
    $params['qty'] = 1;//product quantity
    $_product = $this->productRepository->getById($value);
    $_product->setPrice(0);
    $_product->setBasePrice(0);
    $quote->addProduct($_product,$params); 
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are  adding product by using AddToCart  button ? or directly by controller ?

Comment: I used controller file, not AddToCart button.

Comment: I used this question code in my controller https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216100/i-want-to-set-custom-price-programmatically-to-the-product-magento-2

Comment: I think The Summary Page is load using Knockout.js

Comment: @KushalDani - did you get the solution to your problem. if yes, plz share it.