# I want to set custom price programmatically to the product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to set custom price programmatically and placed order with that price for that product in Magento 2.i have added below code. it set the original price. and original Custom price is updated properly in quote_item table. but custom price is not updated in quote_item table. due to that custom price is not set in order item details.

$quoteItem->setCustomPrice($setPrice);
$quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($setPrice);
$quoteItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);$quoteItem->save();

Comment: Try one of these links https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216100/i-want-to-set-custom-price-programmatically-to-the-product-magento-2
or https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-product-to-cart-with-custom-price-magento-2.html

Comment: Can you share me full code ?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion :
Override `addtocart.phtml` from 
`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view`
 into your theme 
`/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view`

After That you can add a hidden field in form

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()) :?>
<input type="hidden" name="isCustomPrice" value="1"/> <!-- Here -->
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()) :?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       min="0"
                       value="<?= $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
                       class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($buttonTitle) ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button" disabled>
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($buttonTitle) ?></span>
            </button>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now Create A module that will do trigger event and it will set the custom price to your product

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

<br/ >
etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="set_custom_price_to_product" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver" />
    </event>
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_update_after">
        <observer name="update_custom_price_to_product" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

<br/ >
Observer/CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface
     */
    protected $_layout;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_request;
    private $serializer;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface $serializer,
    ) {
        $this->_layout = $layout;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
    }
    /**
     * Add order information into GA block to render on checkout success pages
     *
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        $item = ($item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item);
        $price = 100; //set your price here
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
}
```

Maybe there are many ways to do but i have done it in this way. other suggestions are welcome :)