Overriding Price Determination with Custom Logic
We are looking at setting up a new magento2 site as a frontend for an existing ERP system. Since our pricing methods in the existing ERP system are quite involved, we want to look at overriding the way Magento determines pricing to make a remote call to one of our endpoints rather than running through the typical magento pricing.
I'm wondering how feasible it would be to override the pricing lookups in the Magento logic with our custom pricing determination logic. In order to correctly determine pricing we would need the SKU, order quantity, and customer in the request to our custom endpoint.
Is there a single (or few) place that we could override in Magento to implement our custom pricing lookup logic? I've reviewed a few of the core modules but I'm not really sure where to start in terms of tracking down how magento is determining pricing for items.

You can use custom price, just do your logic based on your business and set the custom price, for reference take a look here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216100/i-want-to-set-custom-price-programmatically-to-the-product-magento-2

@RizwanKhan thanks for the response, but that only seems to be how to override the price when adding an item to a quote object. I'm assuming everything else will still show the system price rather than the overridden one.

well, yes it is, this can not be done by just custom price. you need to modify each component where you want your Price Determination with custom logic for eg, PDP, PLP, cart checkout etc..
